# Fire Scheduling with Triggers in CMMS

Tags: c#, performance

I worked on cmms project .
I have some scheduling , esch of schedule have some triggers (e.g,. Bymeter , byActivity ,ByPeriod).

I wrote some methods to generate workOrder for each Schedule if schedule is ok.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TodayScheduleTaskViewModel>> GetTodayTasks(int page, int recordsPerPage = 50)
    {
        int resultForSkip = page * recordsPerPage;
        var _result = new List<Schedule>();

        bool repeat = true;
        do
        {
            var data = await GetExpression(page, recordsPerPage).Cacheable().ToListAsync();
            if (data.Count == 0) { repeat = false; break; };
            _result.AddRange(Calculate(data).ToList());
            page++;
        } while ((_result.Count < recordsPerPage && repeat));


        return _result.Select(row => new TodayScheduleTaskViewModel
        {
            //map fields 

        }).ToList();
    }
```

and :

```
 private IQueryable<Schedule> GetExpression(int page, int recordsPerPage = 50)
    {
        int resultForSkip = page * recordsPerPage;

        return _schedules.OrderBy(row => row.Code).Skip(() => resultForSkip).Take(() => recordsPerPage);
    }
```

and Calculate method :

```
 private IEnumerable<Schedule> Calculate(List<Schedule> schedules)
    {
        List<Schedule> result = new List<Schedule>();
        foreach (var schedule in schedules)
        {

            bool IsAllTriggersRequired = schedule.WhenFire == GenerateWorkOrderWhen.AllOfTheTriggersFire ? true : false;
            bool dontContinue = false;

            bool timeFalg = false, meterFlag = false, workFlag = false;
            int countersuccessTriggers = 0;


            foreach (var item in schedule.Triggers)
            {


                switch (item.TypeId)
                {


                    case TriggerType.ByWork:

                        if (dontContinue && !IsAllTriggersRequired) break;
                        int workValue = _equipmentFunctionService.GetAssetWorkValue(schedule.AssetId.Value,schedule.CalculatingType);
                        if ((workValue >= item.WorkValue) && !dontContinue)
                        {
                            workFlag = true;
                            dontContinue = true;
                            countersuccessTriggers++;
                        };
                        break;
                }

            }
            var AllTriggersAvailabe = countersuccessTriggers == schedule.Triggers.Count && IsAllTriggersRequired;
            var AnyTriggersAvailabe = timeFalg || meterFlag || workFlag;


            if (AllTriggersAvailabe || (!IsAllTriggersRequired && AnyTriggersAvailabe))
                result.Add(schedule);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

let's describe method and my goal:

**I want to speed up my query.**

1- Why use `do...While` in `GetTodayTask` :
my GridView Page size is const and I want Just return same records, First I get some Records and pass them to `Calculate()` Method to check some condition and maybe in `Calculate()` Method some records removed  (`result count changed in calculate()`)

Comment: You want to speed up the query but do you know it's slow? Did you test it? How long does it take to execute?

Comment: @t3chb0t yes its slow and its Heavy query because It runs at least 10 query for each schedule . I dont have Unit Test to know how long does it take  . and I want to get best practice from other programmer to change my code

Comment: @t3chb0t and I'm not sure , `do while ` is a good code for that purpse ?

Comment: If you don't know how long it takes to execute the query now, how would you know whether the suggested improvements are actually improvements?

Comment: ok your right . but I need an idea for do while to alwyas get const records if exists

Answer (score 3):

Some notes on your coding style:

- Why do you do `int resultForSkip = page * recordsPerPage;` at the start of `GetTodayTasks`? You never use this variable.
- `var _result = new List<Schedule>();`: the underscore prefix should be used to indicate class-level fields, not variables inside a method. Why even call it `_result`, when `schedules` is far more clear?
- `data` is also way too generic as a name.
- `GetExpression` doesn't return an expression.
- Why is the parameter of `Calculate(List<Schedule> schedules)` a `List<T>`? An `IEnumerable<T>` suffices.
- Don't abbreviate "do not" to "don't" in variable names: `dontContinue`.
- The "Falg" in `timeFalg` should be "Flag".
- `countersuccessTriggers` is improperly capitalized, but it's also badly named. Perhaps `successTriggerCount` would be better.
- There are several places where random blank lines appear. Please clean these.
- Use descriptive names: `foreach (var item in schedule.Triggers)`. Why call it an `item` when it is a `trigger`?
- Why is the property called `TypeId`? Judging from the rest of the code it is an enum value, so why not call it `Type`?
- Method scope variables should be camelCase, so `IsAllTriggersRequired`, `AllTriggersAvailabe`, `AnyTriggersAvailabe` are incorrect.
- Also pay attention to verb conjugations: `IsAllTriggersRequired` should be `areAllTriggersRequired`.
- However, looking at `IsAllTriggersRequired`, `AllTriggersAvailabe` and `AnyTriggersAvailabe` there are more problems beyond those already mentioned: the naming is inconsistent and feels incorrect. Boolean names like "IsAvailabe" are great as property names, but don't work well as variable names. In this case I'd go for `allTriggersAreRequired`, `allTriggersAreAvailabe` and `anyTriggerIsAvailabe`.

Comment: ohh , great , that very good . what about `do while` method ? do you have any idea ?